# How to call function from module and show record in view file using MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am working in MEAN stack and I using the controller and module file.

module.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/allusers', {
    controller: 'usercontroller',
    templateUrl: 'js/view/allusers.html'

  });
});
```

Now I want to call a `usercontroller` function. How can I call function which is 
defined into the controller?

My controller.js file is

```
app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {

  $scope.allusers = function() {

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/addseat',
      data: { email: 'shahjad.ahmad89@gmail.com', password: 123456 }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      if (response.data.error) {
        alert("Invalid email pasword");
      } else {
        $scope.dp = response.data;
        $localStorage.pp = $scope.dp;
      }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      alert("Invalid email pasword");
    });
  }
});
```

How to call the `allusers` function from the module and how to display the record into view file?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `allusers` function inside your controller by default when your controller loads as

```
$scope.allusers();
```

You can also call it through any button click or other event using `ng-click` attribute.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="allusers()"/>
```

And display the value as,

For single value,
    `<div>{{dp}}</div>`

For multiple values use `ng-repeat`,

```
<div ng-repeat="d in dp">{{d}}</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can I call any function depend on the url  like http://localhost:3000/#/allusers when this url hit is it possible automatically alluser()  function call

Comment: Yes, below your ``allusers`` function inside your controller add this line,   $scope.allusers();
It will automatically call the function when page loads.

Comment: Though you don't need to define it as a scope function when you are going to call that function from inside controller only. You can define it as normal function and then call as ``allusers()``